# c# Run a .NET assembly bytes

Tags: c#

I'am using the code below to execute a .NET Application :

```
 byte[] Data = Convert.FromBase64String(data); // application
 Assembly a = Assembly.Load(Data);
 MethodInfo method = a.EntryPoint;
 object o = a.CreateInstance(method.Name);
 method.Invoke(o, null);
```

but i can't seems to be reading the whole application it only reads the first Class for example i have some methods and some events on that application that's going to be raised and do some works the application doesnt respond it do only Methods on the EntryPoint i want to be able to run the whole application with its multiple classes .

Comment: `byte[] Data = Data;`???

Comment: its just an example its a Base64String Converted to bytes `byte[] Data = Convert.FromBase64String(data);`

Comment: and what is in `data`?

Comment: data is a a.Net application bytes converted to Base64String

Comment: If you want an answer, you need to produce a complete example that reproduces the problem including the assembly you're trying to load.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Its exactly the code i'am using but it only reads the entryPoint of the Application i want to run the whole app

Comment: Why are you trying to create an instance of the method name? Shouldn't you be creating an instance of the method's declaring type?

Comment: Also `a.CreateInstance(method.Name)` is nonsensical. `CreateInstance` expects a type name, but you're passing it a method name. Also, since the entry point is a static method, why are you creating any instances at all instead of just invoking the entry point.

Comment: @Rob its the issue , i don't know how to declare a type

Comment: @CodesInChaos a quick example pls ?

Comment: @Huster `var o = Activator.CreateInstance(method.DeclaringType);` ?

Comment: You didn't include the signature of the `Main` method you're trying to call. So how am I supposed to know?

Comment: @CodesInChaos My main is subscribing to an event and when ever i raise that event through my sql server using a Query it doesnt Do nothing , i created to lauch a messageBox whenever that event happen , i tried it using the application it self but when i want to invoke it using the code above it doesnt works

Comment: @Rob I'am sorry i didnt get it Right , i want to create instant of the whole Application because it doesnt works it only call the methods once

Comment: @Rob Sorry again , i just got it =) thanks what if my Application has a Form My Main entrypoint launch start that form i aways get a exception c# `setCompatibleTextRenderingDefault must be called`